# Gekko optimal control. How to create multiple termination objectives/conditions?

Tags: python, gekko

So I am simulating plane flight. The plane flies certain distance (`pathx` and `pathy` variables) and then the simulation stops, when certain `pathx` and `pathy` values are reached. The solver is trying to minimize the fuel consumption `(m.Maximize(mass*tf*final)`, by maximizing the mass value. The solver controls the accelerator pedal position (`Tcontr`).

Right now the termination condition is defined like this:

For X axis:

```
m.Equation(x*final<=pathx)
```

and

```
m.Minimize(final*(x-pathx)**2)
```

And for Y axis:

```
m.Equation(y*final<=pathy)
```

and

```
m.Minimize(final*(y-pathy)**2)
```

And right now the simulation ends when the desired X value is achieved, while desired Y values is not being achieved.

How do I force the simulation to end when both desired (X and Y) values are achieved?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
import math
#Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

#Time points
nt = 11
tm =  np.linspace(0,100,nt)
m.time = tm

# Variables
Ro = m.Var(value=1.1)#air density
g = m.Const(value=9.80665)
pressure = m.Var(value=101325)#
T = m.Var(value=281,lb=100)#temperature
T0 = m.Const(value=288)#temperature at see level
S = m.Const(value=122.6)
Cd = m.Const(value=0.1)#drag coef
Cl = m.Var(value=1)#lift couef
FuelFlow = m.Var()
D = m.Var(value=25000,lb=0)#drag
Thrmax = m.Const(value=200000)#maximum throttle
Thr = m.Var()#throttle
V = m.Var(value=100,lb=50,ub=240)#velocity
gamma = m.Var(value=0)# Flight-path angle
gammaa = gamma.value
Xi = m.Var(value=0)# Heading angle
Xii = Xi.value
x = m.Var(value=0,lb=0)#x position
y = m.Var(value=0,lb=0)#y position
h = m.Var(value=1000,lb=0)# height
mass = m.Var(value=60000,lb=10000)
pathx = m.Const(value=50000) #intended distance length
pathy = m.Const(value=50000)
L = m.Var(value=0.1)#lift

p = np.zeros(nt)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

m.options.MAX_ITER=10000 # iteration number

#Fixed Variable
tf = m.FV(value=1,lb=0.0001,ub=1000.0)#
tf.STATUS = 1

# Controlled parameters
Tcontr = m.MV(value=0.2,lb=0.1,ub=1)# solver controls throttle pedal position
Tcontr.STATUS = 1
Tcontr.DCOST = 0

#Mu = m.Var(value=0)
Mu = m.MV(value=0,lb=-1.5,ub=1.5)# solver controls bank angle 
Mu.STATUS = 1
Mu.DCOST = 0

Muu = Mu.value

# Equations
m.Equation(Thr==Tcontr*Thrmax)
m.Equation(FuelFlow==0.75882*(1+(V/2938.5)))
m.Equation(D==0.5*Ro*(V**2)*Cd*S)
m.Equation(mass.dt()==tf*(-Thr*(FuelFlow/60000)))#
m.Equation(V.dt()==tf*((Thr-D)/mass))#
m.Equation(x.dt()==tf*(V*(math.cos(gammaa.value))*(math.cos(Xii.value))))#
m.Equation(x*final<=pathx)
#pressure and density part
m.Equation(T==T0-(0.0065*h))
m.Equation(pressure==101325*(1-(0.0065*h)/T0)**((g*0.0289652)/(8.31446*0.0065)))#
m.Equation(Ro*(8.31446*T)==(pressure*0.0289652))
#2D addition part
m.Equation(L==0.5*Ro*(V**2)*Cl*S)
m.Equation(Xi.dt()==tf*((L*math.sin(Muu.value))/(mass*V)))
m.Equation(y.dt()==tf*(V*(math.cos(gammaa.value))*(math.sin(Xii.value))))#
m.Equation(y*final<=pathy)

# Objective Function
m.Minimize(final*(x-pathx)**2) #1D part
m.Minimize(final*(y-pathy)**2) #2D part
m.Maximize(mass*tf*final) #objective function
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.NODES = 2 # it was 3 before
m.options.MV_TYPE = 1
m.options.SOLVER = 3
#m.open_folder() # to search for infeasibilities
m.solve()

tm = tm * tf.value[0]
    
fig, axs = plt.subplots(8)
fig.suptitle('Results')
axs[0].plot(tm,Tcontr,'r-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$Tcontr$')
axs[0].legend(loc='best')
axs[1].plot(tm,V.value,'b-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$V$')
axs[1].legend(loc='best')
axs[2].plot(tm,x.value,'r--',LineWidth=2,label=r'$x$')
axs[2].legend(loc='best')
axs[3].plot(tm,D.value,'g-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$D$')
axs[3].legend(loc='best')
axs[4].plot(tm,mass.value,'g:',LineWidth=2,label=r'$mass$')
axs[4].legend(loc='best')
axs[5].plot(tm,T.value,'p-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$T$')
axs[5].legend(loc='best')
axs[6].plot(tm,Mu.value,'p-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$Mu$')
axs[6].legend(loc='best')
axs[7].plot(tm,y.value,'p-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$y$')
axs[7].legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
#plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.show()
```

**Important Update**

It looks like termination conditions (all of the above) work as intended. Y axis values can not be reached, because it looks like the math involving it is not working properly.

Y value is being calculated by this equation: [image]
I have turned into this: `m.Equation(y.dt()==tf*(V*(math.cos(gammaa.value))*(math.sin(Xii.value))))`

Where: `V` is true air speed (works properly);

`tf` is a variable that controls simulation time (works properly);

`gammaa` is derived from `gamma`, which is flight-path angle, which is 0 in this simulation (works properly);

`Xii` is derived from `Xi`, which is heading angle (**the main culprit**).

`Xi` value is defined by this equation: [image]

I turned it into this: `m.Equation(Xi.dt()==tf*((L*math.sin(Muu.value))/(mass*V)))`

Where: `L` is lift force (works properly);

`mass` is mass (works properly);

`V` is true air speed (works properly);

`Muu` is derived from `Mu`, which is bank angle, the solver controlled variable (probably the bad apple here).

`Y` value calculation should be working like this: solver changes `Mu`, which affects The heading angle `Xi`, which then should affect `Y` value.

After some experiments it looks like the range of changes of the `Mu` value during the simulation is so small, that it barely affects Y value. But it should be a lot wider since `Mu` boundaries are quite wide `(lb=-1.5,ub=1.5)`. I tried to remove those boundaries, but it did not affect the results of the simulation.

What could be messing up everything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a hard terminal constraint for both:

```py
m.Equation((x-pathx)*final==0)
m.Equation((y-pathy)*final==0)
```

Alternatively, increase the weight on the terminal condition.

```py
w = 1e3
m.Minimize(w*final*(x-pathx)**2) #1D part
m.Minimize(w*final*(y-pathy)**2) #2D part
```

You may need to use one or both strategies. Terminal conditions can be challenging to solve.

**Response to Important Update**

Use the Gekko functions with `m.sin()` and `m.cos()` instead of the `math` functions. Also, don't use `.value` in the equations. Gekko needs the full symbolic graph so that it can compile the equations into byte-code and produce function evaluations and the derivatives with automatic differentiation.

```py
m.Equation(y.dt()==tf*(V*(m.cos(gammaa))*(m.sin(Xii))))
```

It also helps to avoid divide by zero by multiplying any denominator over to the other side.

```py
m.Equation(mass*V*Xi.dt()==tf*((L*m.sin(Muu))))
```

Comment: Thank you! But hard terminal constraint on its own generates this issue: Restoration phase in the restoration phase failed. If I implement both hard constraint and increase the weight of the terminal condition, then the program runs until it runs out of MAX_ITER iterations.

Comment: The effect of implementation of increased weight alone is negligible and does not achieve  serious increase of final y value.

Comment: Thanks for reporting on those. Have you tried both methods with the hard constraint and soft (objective) constraint? You may need to solve without the hard constraints and then add it and solve again with `m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0`. That may help the solver find a solution.

Comment: So, I have tested some things, and it looks like all soft termination conditions are working as intended, but there are other things that do not work as intended. I will describe them at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Try using the Gekko trigonometric functions `m.sin()` and `m.cos()`.

Comment: So, since I am deriving Muu value from Mu like this: Muu = Mu.value, then does it mean that if I want to use m.cos and other trigonometric functions, I need to stop deriving Muu value like that and start to just use Mu and other similar variables in their pure form?

Comment: I removed all the derived values (like Muu) an replaced them with their original counterparts. The simulation returned an error after 41711 iterations: Restoration phase is called at point that is almost feasible,
  with constraint violation 7.275958e-011. Abort.
Restoration phase in the restoration phase failed.                 Before that change the simulation was not returning such errors.

Comment: The prior problem used the Mu.value (fixed floating point number) in the place of the `Mu` manipulated variable. It is a more difficult problem to solve so I'm not surprised that the solver may not have found a solution. Try setting the bounds more restrictive such as `Mu = m.MV(value=0,lb=-0.5,ub=0.5)` or add a move suppression penalty with `Mu.DCOST=1e-3`. These can both help the solver find a solution. You may also want to try `m.options.SOLVER=1`.

Comment: Implementation of Mu = m.MV(value=0,lb=-0.5,ub=0.5) and Mu.DCOST=1e-3 does not achieve feasibility after 100000 iterations. But change the solver to 1 results in solution almost instantly, but it takes very long simulation time (like 80000 seconds, which is way too much for this situation) and it drastically overshoots its targets (by a factor of 10-100), both X an Y, and it has to tone them down during the second half of the simulation time. Why would it overshoot the targets THAT much?

Comment: With solver = 1 I returned the previous Mu boundaries and it started to overshoot a lot less, but its still reaches X or Y values that are 2-4 times higher than intended.

Comment: Maybe try constraining the solution to see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! After implementation of ub for x and y, it did not change much, it would still fluctuate wildly during the simulation, it would still overshoot a bit, it would take too long to reach the destination. But after I lover the ub of tf, it started to fluctuate a lot less and with very limited tf it shows very good results. So, it looks like SOLVER=1 is not as aggressive at reaching the destination, as SOLVER = 3 was.

Comment: But, still the new problem appeared after solver=1 was implemented. Values of T and h started to fluctuate wildly during the simulations. I can not understand how it could be happening, since there are no equations, that are capable of changing the values of T and h.

Comment: It looks like with solver=1, the solver "forgot" how to manage tf values. I found that out by testing different tf ub values. I recognized, that after lower tf ub, the value that needs to be maximized(mass) is bigger, than before, with the bigger tf ub. The solver had the ability to maximize mass value a lot better, but it looks like it just "chose "not to.

Comment: It looks like the IPOPT solver may be a better choice for this problem. Each solver has different strengths. Did APOPT report a successful solution? It may have found a different local optimum.

Comment: Yes, Apopt generates successful solutions. It looks like the main problem right now is the fluctuations of values like T and h. I don't understand  why would they change? h should be static, hence T should not change too.

Comment: I tried to make h constant and then T returned back to normal. So the question is: Why h would be changing? There are no equations that are explicitly calculating value of h.

Comment: The variable `h` is in this equation `m.Equation(pressure==101325*(1-(0.0065*h)/T0)**((g*0.0289652)/(8.31446*0.0065)))` and possibly others. If it appears in an equation then the solver may change it to satisfy the equation. Variables don't need to be on the right or left hand side. The solver puts all equations into residual form before solving it so it is equivalent to `m.Equation(0=pressure-101325*(1-(0.0065*h)/T0)**((g*0.0289652)/(8.31446*0.0065)))`.

Comment: Is there a way to make solver to stop modifying certain variables? Outside defining them as m.Const?

Comment: If they are a variable then the solver can modify them. Alternatively, they can be set as `m.Param()`.

Comment: Git it! Thank you!